# Exclude WCF datasource file from SonarQube analysis

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

After updating to the MSBuild Runner V1 SonarQube picks up the reference to WCF Datasource files and tries to analyse it. This breaks ofc due to the length of the full path being longer than limit set by MS and logs the following error:

```
Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)"
```

Is there a way to exclude datasource files. We tried adding `*.datasource` to the exclusion tab but made no difference.

Using `MSbuild.SonarQube.Runner` V1 with SonarQube 5.1

Comment: I've posted an answer explaining how to exclude individual files by changing the MSBuild project file. However, I would have expected the standard exclusion mechanism to work too. Which analysis property did you set - sonar.global.exclusions? sonar.exclusions?

Comment: I added the exclusion Settings->Exclusions

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude individual files from analysis by setting the metadata property *SonarQubeExclude* in the individual project files e.g.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="MyFile.cs">
    <!-- Exclude the file from analysis -->
    <SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/appendix-2.md#excluding-artefacts-from-analysis) on GitHub for more info.

You should be able to use an MSBuild [ItemGroupDefinition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629392.aspx) to automatically set the metadata item for all *.datasource files.

Comment: Not sure if I can mark this as an answer, we had to revert to the sonarqube C# 4.0 plugin and use the Sonar Runner because Codecoverage is not begin picked up with  C# plugin 4.1 and MSBuild runner 1  and no-one is able to provide any information about it. The previous version excluded *.DataSource files without any configuration.
@duncanpMS